# Can a base class sometimes initialize a derived class's member?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Does this program have well-defined behavior?

```
struct Foo;

struct FooImpl {
  FooImpl();
};

struct Foo : FooImpl {
  int bar;
};

FooImpl::FooImpl() {
  static_cast<Foo *>(this)->bar = 0;
}

int main() {
  return Foo().bar;
}
```

Of particular note is that `Foo::bar` is default initialized. I know this certainly is bad if `Foo::bar` gets initialized by `Foo`, hence this particular example.

Please keep in mind that this is a simplified example to illustrate a case. I'm interested in what the C++ spec has to say about this (and not whether or not this is good or bad code stylistically).

Comment: Are you trying to create a version of the Pimpl pattern? Do you know about the [Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Kinda... but I'm mostly interested simply out of interest's sake.

Comment: I generally consider myself a C++ expert, but wow, you have me stumped. I'd have to check the spec.

Answer (score 6):

In general, parent can access children's members. Like the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

However, accessing them in destructors and constructors leads directly to UB.

```
 FooImpl::FooImpl() 
 {
    static_cast<Foo *>(this)->bar = 0;
 }
```

This is UB because `Foo` and subsequently `bar` have not been constructed yet and you already access it (and modify it!). Similarly in destructor - `bar` would already be deleted by this point. Instead you could create `Initialize()` method in `FooImpl` with the same body and call it in `Foo`'s constructor then it would be legal.